# Make that divs growing from bottom to top depending on each content size

Tags: html, css

I have that small fiddle for testing:

```css
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 50vh;
      width: 600px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    .content-one {
      border: 1px solid green;
        display: flex;
    }

    .content-two {
      border: 1px solid blue;
        display: flex;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="content-one">

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

</div>

<div class="content-two">

 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</div>

</div>
```

but I can't figure out how did I get two divs growing from bottom to top depending on its content height.

If I have only one content container it is no problem but what if I have two dynamically growing divs inside my wrapper which needs to expand from bottom up?

Comment: It's not clear what it is you are trying to do...something like this - > https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WEKwjK

Comment: hey paulie_D thank you thats it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add below css in your wrapper class

```
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-height: 50vh;
        width: 600px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 1em;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
```